# Python dict issue outside loop

Tags: python, dictionary

I am reading yaml file using `pyyaml` and looking up for a particular property in yaml file and fetching all values of it in a list.

I have dict with set as value and for each prop values I am adding respecting yaml file into the set , so dict would loop like:

```
prop1 => yaml1 , yaml2 , prop2 => yaml3 , prop3 => yaml4, yaml1 etc...
```

I am populating dict inside the loop , however once all yaml files reading are done then returning the dict from outer loop does always return it empty dict.

code snippet :

```py
  def populate_records():
    records_map = defaultdict(set)
    path = 'abc/xyz'
    pattern = '*.yaml'
    prop_key = "abc::def"
    files = glob.glob(path + os.sep + pattern)
    for filename in files:
       f_name = os.path.basename(filename).rsplit(".", 1)[0]
       with open(filename, 'r') as f:
          node = yaml.load(f)
          if node is not None:
            for property_name in node:
               if prop_key == property_name:
                 prop_list = node[property_name]
                 break
            for prop in prop_list:
               records_map[prop].add(f_name)
    return records_map
```

Can anyone please help me to figure out what's the issue with above code?

Comment: At a guess, `prop_key == property_name` is never true. What debugging have you attempted?

Comment: suppose yaml files are having property with values like :
abc::def:
- xxx
- yyy
- zzz

Would the above check not work?

Comment: @SiHa, prop_key == property_name works perfectly , even I printed prop_list after the break statement and it prints this property values for each yaml file . however , there is some catch in next for loop where I am adding file name against each prop value, because once all data gets added to the map when I print or return this map from outer loop ..it gives me empty dict.

Comment: Even , printed map inside outer loop and able to see data is getting added for each files. But as soon as I tried to print it at same level where return statement is there..it won't print anything...is something wrong I am doing?

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to fix it , it throws null pointer exception on list and due to this dict always returns as empty.

Working code :

```
def populate_records():
records_map = defaultdict(set)
path = 'abc/xyz'
pattern = '*.yaml'
prop_key = "abc::def"
files = glob.glob(path + os.sep + pattern)
for filename in files:
   f_name = os.path.basename(filename).rsplit(".", 1)[0]
   with open(filename, 'r') as f:
      node = yaml.load(f)
      if node is not None:
        for property_name in node:
           if prop_key == property_name:
             prop_list = node[property_name]
             if prop_list is None:
                break
             for prop in prop_list:
                records_map[prop].add(f_name)
                break 
return records_map
```